# Z test for proportion of sums

Tags: inference, proportion, z-test

I want to perform a Z-test for two variables: $ X $ (Buyer proportion) and $ Y $ (Spent proportion  \$ ). Below the table you can see a dummy example of the data I have:

[image]

Let's assume the conditions to apply a Z-test are met (populations normally distributed, random samples,...).Then, to see if there is a significant difference in buyer proportion  we can apply the procedure of two proportion test:

$$ Z= \frac{\hat{p}_1-\hat{p}_2}{\sqrt{p_0(1-p_0)(\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2})}}$$ where $p_0=\frac{p_1 \times n_1 + p_2 \times n_2}{n_1 + n_2}$

For ProductID==B, we have:

$$ Z= \frac{0.17143-0.16286}{\sqrt{0.165(1-0.165)(\frac{1}{350}+\frac{1}{1050})}}=0.37413$$ where $p_0=\frac{0.17143 \times 350 + 0.16286 \times 1050}{350 + 1050}=0.165$

With the Z score we calculate P-value and so on.

**When I try to replicate this but for Spent proportion I get confused because Spent proportion is based on sum**. For instance:

$$ProductID==B;Y_1=\frac{\$747}{\$4778}=0.15632$$

Does it make sense to use *N purchases* in Group 1 ($n_1$ = 1050) and Group 2 ($n_2$ = 3255) to estimate $p_0$?

Should I assess the significant difference in spent proportion differently?

If you have any literature that talks about this. I would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.